# Divisibility of the Vandermonde determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

In *Linear Algebra* by G. E. Shilov, there is an example describing the proof of the equation of the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix (denoted $W(x_1,...,x_n)$):

> "$W(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $x_n$, with coefficients depending on $x_1,...x_{n-1}$. This polynomial vanishes if $x_n$ takes any of the values $x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}$, since the determinant has two identical columns. Hence by a **familiar theorem of elementary algebra** the polynomial $W(x_1,...,x_n)$ is divisible by the product $(x_n-x_1)...(x_n-x_{n-1})$."

What is this **familiar theorem of elementary algebra**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

briefly, if for a polynomial $f(x)$ and we have $f(a) = 0$, then $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$ (and conversely). i think you may read about this under the heading *remainder theorem* or *little Bezout theorem* - see for example  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)